# Is it possible to integrate Microsoft rule set (FxCop rules) into Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, fxcop, stylecop, code-cleanup

We have a big legacy solution (170+ projects) and want to:

1. Perform initial code cleanup automatically for all our codebase with rules defined by us.
2. Have plugin available to integrate with ReSharper, so that we could see warnings/hints/suggestions in code and apply quick fixes with Ctrl + Enter.
3. Have config in source control, so it can be shared between all team members and coding style checked by TeamCity after every commit.

The best what we found for this is to use R# + StyleCop for this, but I recently found out that there are many more rules for code quality used by FxCop and Visual Studio - Microsoft Code Analisys Rule set:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264925.aspx

StyleCop rule set is not compatible with it. We would prefer following Microsoft rule set, not StyleCop one.

Question: is there a way to integrate Microsoft rule set (customized) into ReSharper and have all three above - cleanup, quick fixes, TeamCity integration with Microsoft rules? After a day of googling I did not find how to do it. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Have you considered NDepend? It comes with 130 default code rules, but the flagship feature is that it makes it *very* easy to write your own code rules since a NDepend code rule is a LINQ query. See the default code rules here http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html  Also it is integrated in VS (2013, 2012, 2010,2008) and analysis and rules execution is pretty fast, like less than 10 seconds on a large code base.   (Disclaimer: I am working in the NDepend team)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like NDepend is quite interesting tool, but we are using R# for many things which NDepend covers, and we cannot afford one more tool.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be achievable in resharper now.

> ReSharper allows you to configure an extensive set of formatting rules and enforce them in your code. These rules are applied when ReSharper produces new code with code completion and code generation features, code templates and refactorings. The formatting rules can be also applied to the existing code in the current selection, current file, or in a larger scope up to the entire solution.

Source: [Jetbrains Resharper Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html)